# A picture is worth a million memories!

Tags: visual, rebus

[image]

> **What does the above picture refer to?**

Hint:

> The third part has numbers that are ......... ?

Comment: rebus tag maybe? +1!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering the date this question was posted, I believe this puzzle commemorates:

> The Apollo 11 moon landing on 20 July 1969, fifty years ago.

Explanation of clues (one small step at a time...):

> 1. Clock showing 00:09 - this could represent '60' (minutes in an hour) and '9' (the minutes represented in the image) to give **'69** - the year of the mission.
>  2. The Greek flag, representing the Greek god **Apollo**.
>  3. A list of numbers all divisible by **11**.
>  4. A South African flag + reverse-cycle symbol - possibly contributing *an 'SA'* but *reversing* the 'an' to get **NASA**.
>  5. A picture of **space**.
>  6. **Golf** - a game which was played on the moon during the mission.
>  7. The **Pacific Ocean** - where the lunar module splashed down on return to Earth on 24 July 1969.
>  8. A military vehicle known as the **Eagle** 6x6 - the name of the Lunar Module in question, as in 'The Eagle has landed'.

Comment: Wow! This seems correct, I would think...

Comment: Excellent!!!!...

Answer (score 3):

## VERY Partial Answer

1. > I dunno!
2. > Flag of Greece
3. > The first three seem to be **biprime** or **semiprime**.
4. > SA... repeat?
5. > Galaxy golf... ?
6. > The Pacific Ocean
7. > A military vehicle called the Eagle, I believe.

Comment: Rot13(Gur 6gu bar vf pbeerpg, naq vs lbh svaq gur anzr bs gung zvyvgnel iruvpyr, lbh'yy nyzbfg trg gur nafjre. Nyfb Fbhgu Nsevpn≡ FN naq vafgrnq bs ntnva gel fbzr bgure rdhvinyrag jbeq.) (+1)

Comment: Number 2  is rot13(gur synt bs Terrpr), and I believe 7 is  rot13(Rntyr 6k6 yvtug gnpgvpny nezberq iruvpyr) found here https://www.army-technology.com/projects/eagle-6x6-light-tactical-vehicle-army/